# Add dynamic class to element

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have variable classes called "fx -..." I would like to add a class named without suffix "fx-".
For example "fadeUp".
How can I do?

```
<h1 class="way-animate fx-fadeUp">Title</h1>
```

Comment: You can do this with JS

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking so you can construct a good question which will get answered faster and most likely upvoted

Comment: How is your HTML being generated? Do you need to remove the `fx-`? There are selectors that allow you to target partial class names.

Comment: Whether you like to replace this class or to keep it and another class without suffix my answer solves your problem with jQuery. If you mean by variable, an already defined class list that's being generated somehow, you better explain the missing part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to replace any fx-* class with the other portion of the class.

First we get the list of classes of H1, then we loop and when we find a match we just do whatever we like.
Well if you want to keep it, you just remove the `removeClass` line of my code.

```
var classList = $('h1').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
$.each(classList, function(index, item) {
    if (item.includes('fx-')) {
        $("h1").removeClass (item);
        var newclass=item.replace(/fx-/gi, "");
        $("h1").addClass(newclass);
    }
});
```

[UPDATED] You can Have a look here : https://jsfiddle.net/k86oqwn9/1/

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed. ;)

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, I think you want to know 'how to add dynamic class name'. Can you please elaborate your what you asking for.

suppose you have a variable

```
let cls = 'fx-fadeUp';
```

You can easily remove `fx-` using javascript like this

```
cls = cls.substr(3, cls.length); // now cls = 'fadeUP'
```

Then you can also add class using javascript like this

```
document.querySelector('.way-animate').classList.add(cls);
```

**OR**, if you want to select all classes starting with something like `fx-`, you can do it with css also like this

```
[class^="fx-"] {
    /* Your css styles */   
}
```

**AND/OR**, if you use jQuery, there is build in function for to add & remove class: `addClass` & `removeClass`

```
$(selector).addClass('className');
$(selector).removeClass('className');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var prefix = "fx-";
var suffix  = "fadeUp";
var strClass = prefix+suffix;
$("h1").addClass(strClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you could use the `addClass` function:

```
// locate element
var h1el = $('h1.way-animate');

// add css class
h1el.addClass('another-class');
```

Ref.: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/